# How do I take max value of a pandas dataframe column and find the corresponding value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I want to take max value of a pandas dataframe column and find the corresponding value in another column? Let's assume there are not duplicates in the maximum value, so you are always returning only one value. For example,

```
GPA   ID
2.3  Tina1
3.4  Bob1
3.6  Lia1
2.9  Tina2
4.0  Blake1
4.5  Conor2
```

Here the max GPA is 4.5, but I want to return the corresponding id for the max GPA, so I would return Conor2. I am unsure of how to do this, so help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
df.loc[df.GPA == df.GPA.max(), 'ID']
```

You get

```
5    Conor2
```

If you don't want the index but just the value, try

```
df.loc[df.GPA == df.GPA.max(), 'ID'].values[0]
```

You get

```
'Conor2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a quick comment. Instead of using `df.loc[...].values[0]` you can directly access the content of the resulting Series with `df.loc[...].item()`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `idxmax`:

```
df.set_index('ID').idxmax()
```

Output:

```
GPA    Conor2
dtype: object
```

A series with a single value `Conor2`.

Comment: Ah! Didn't think of idxmax() :) +1

Comment: @A-Za-z Yeah, there is overhead with creating the index, but if the index already exists it is a good method.