# Get value from grouped data frame maximum in another column

Tags: python-3.x, group-by

Return and assign the value of column `c` based on the maximum value of column `b` in a grouped data frame, grouped on column `a`.

I'm trying to return and assign (ideally in a different column) the value of column `c`, determined by the row with the maximum in column `b` (which are dates). The dataframe is grouped by column `a`, but I keep getting errors.  The data frame is relatively large, with over 16,000 rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'],
                   'b': ['2008-11-01', '2022-07-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-02-01', '2018-02-01', '2008-11-01', '2014-11-01', '2008-11-01', '2022-07-01'],
                   'c': [numpy.NaN,6,8,2,1,numpy.NaN,6,numpy.NaN,7]})
df['b'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['b'])
df

    a   b   c
0   a   2008-11-01  NaN
1   a   2022-07-01  6.0
2   a   2017-02-01  8.0
3   b   2017-02-01  2.0
4   b   2018-02-01  1.0
5   b   2008-11-01  NaN
6   c   2014-11-01  6.0
7   c   2008-11-01  NaN
8   c   2022-07-01  7.0
```

I  want the following result:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   a   2008-11-01  NaN 8.0
1   a   2022-07-01  6.0 8.0
2   a   2017-02-01  8.0 8.0
3   b   2017-02-01  2.0 1.0
4   b   2018-02-01  1.0 1.0
5   b   2008-11-01  NaN 1.0
6   c   2014-11-01  6.0 7.0
7   c   2008-11-01  NaN 7.0
8   c   2022-07-01  7.0 7.0
```

I've tried the following, but grouped series ('SeriesGroupBy') cannot be cast to another dtype:

```
df['d'] = df.groupby('a').b.astype(np.int64).max()[df.c].reset_index()
```

I've set column `b` to int before running the above code, but get an error saying none of the values in `c` are in the index.

```
None of [Index([....values in column c...\n dtype = 'object', name = 'a', length = 16280)] are in the [index]
```

I've tried expanding out the command but errors (which I just realized relate to no alternative values being given in the pd.where function - but I don't know how to give the correct value):

```
df= df.groupby('a')

df['d'] = df.['c'].where(grouped['b'] == grouped['b'].max())
```

I've also tried using solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73482806/min-max-value-of-a-column-based-on-values-of-another-column-grouped-by-and-tran), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263437/how-to-get-value-of-a-column-based-on-the-maximum-of-another-column-in-case-of-d), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938796/how-do-i-take-max-value-of-a-pandas-dataframe-column-and-find-the-corresponding).

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the first three values should be `6.0` (because maximum date for group `a` is `2022-07-01` with value `6`):

```py
df["d"] = df["a"].map(
    df.groupby("a").apply(lambda x: x.loc[x["b"].idxmax(), "c"])
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   a          b    c    d
0  a 2008-11-01  NaN  6.0
1  a 2022-07-01  6.0  6.0
2  a 2017-02-01  8.0  6.0
3  b 2017-02-01  2.0  1.0
4  b 2018-02-01  1.0  1.0
5  b 2008-11-01  NaN  1.0
6  c 2014-11-01  6.0  7.0
7  c 2008-11-01  NaN  7.0
8  c 2022-07-01  7.0  7.0
```

Comment: You are both correct and right.  This fixed my problem perfectly.  I hadn't known about the lambda function before, and this will make my life a whole lot easier now.